# django: creating a new model from existing model and displaying it in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My existing django project has `admin.py` as

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ScholarProfile
admin.site.register(ScholarProfile)
```

and `models.py` as

```
class ScholarProfile(models.Model):
   author_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
   profile_url= models.URLField(max_length=200, primary_key= True)
   Company= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
   Website= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
   publication_title= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500))
   normalized_citations= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), null= True)
   citations= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), null= True)
   coAuthors= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), null= True)
   created_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
   country= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   publications= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Tcitations= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Hindex= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Gindex= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Mindex= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Oindex= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Eindex= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   Hmedian= models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
   TNCc= models.CharField(max_length=100, default= '00', )
   Year= ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return (self.author_name)
```

I want to create a new model, say `AuthorPublications` , with only some fields, say `Company` and `Year` from the above class.How can use them in this new class (Inherit them ?) .Also, this new model should be related to the above model's `author_name` (Foreign key?)

Comment: Say, the name of new model is ScholarDetails

Comment: you can refer from doc link: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#fields`  @ADITYA BISOI

Comment: Your question is not very clear, do you want to create a model like ResearchPaper with title, citations, and authors? in that case ScholarProfile to ResearchPaper is a many-to-many relationship, you are using ArrayField for many-to-many relationships that will create data redundancy later on.

Comment: @AviKKi yes a new model, but only with the above three fields, so that I can register it in admin